# No messages being sent by celery beat (using django-celery-beat)

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat, django-celery-beat

I am in the process of upgrading to celery 5.x for a Django project. Since there is no longer a `@scheduled_task` decorator, I changed all of those to `@shared_task` and wrote some code to create `CrontabSchedule` instances and associate `PeriodicTask` instances with those for each task that should run on a schedule. I am invoking that from a `beat_init` signal receiver. I'm running celery worker & beat as separate processes.

I am logging info from the function that sets up the `CrontabSchedule` and `PeriodicTask` instances, and I see that log output from the celery beat process. Immediately after that, I see a `DatabaseScheduler:` Schedule changed." message. That's all as expected and good.

Subsequently, however, celery beat just sits and does nothing. beat never sends any messages, and as a result, celery worker never executes any scheduled tasks.

In `django-admin shell_plus`, `PeriodicTask.objects.all()` shows me many scheduled tasks with schedules that all look as they should. Here's 1 example from the output that should be running once per minute, every day:

```
<PeriodicTask: dhnetwork.tasks.send_queued_mail: {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59} {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23} * {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12} {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} (m/h/dM/MY/d) America/Los_Angeles>
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong and/or how to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was creating an instance of `crontab` to validate values and then copying values from the properties of the `crontab` instance to fields of the ``CrontabSchedule instance, but the properties of `crontab` are set objects. When writing those values to string fields, we get the `repr` of the `set` as the values, and those are not valid.

In the `all_as_schedule` method in schedulers.py, that results in a `ValueError` which is caught and ignored, so the task is silently not added to the schedule.